# CountA function parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm debugging an VBA code issue and I have found the following line of code for which I don't understand the meaning.

```
=COUNTA(R[-1]C[3]:R[-1]C[31])
```

How can counting the number of empty cells can contain a reference to a negative cell (R[-1]).

Comment: It's relative, it's one row up from cell in which formula is placed

Comment: `R[0]` is the row of the cell this formula is written in. So `R[-1]` is the cell above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General Notes:**

- R represent the rows
- C represent the columns
- In order to count Blank cells is better to use `=COUNTBLANK()`

**Negative:**

- **Above** the cell that you have selected
- **Left** from the cell that you have selected

**Positive:**

- **Below** the cell that you have selected
- **Right** from the cell that you have selected

**Example:**

**Image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTBLANK(R[2]C[-2]:R[8]C[-2])"
    End With

End Sub
```

**So,**

- Selected cell: C3
- Range: (A3:A9)
- R2 & R8 are positive because are below selected cell
- C[-2] is negative because are left from the selected cell